Storage ops / gas spent
Is it possible to know the amount of storage operations (or gas spent) that are between, let's say 4 functions, or a full contract?
Is foundry capable of this?
Thanks!

This post might answer your question.

Seems like that's for contract deployment. Gotta dig deeper to see if it can do what I want to achieve @SYEDASADKAZMI

It actually gives gas usage for the functions within the contract as well.

According to my knowledge direct measurement of gas usage between functions in a deployed smart contract isn't possible. It's like measuring flour used for each step in a baked cake. Gas is tracked at the instruction level, not the function level in the compiled code (similar to how a recipe doesn't track flour per step).
However, tools like Foundry can help estimate gas usage indirectly:

Reference: Here is an example:
you can learn more foundary book gas

